# Why is Entity Framework navigation property null?

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am use code first model with a relationship below

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserSchool { get; set; }

    public UserProfileData UserProfileData { get; set; }

    public int? MedicalSpecialtyId { get; set; }
    public virtual MedicalSpecialty MedicalSpecialty { get; set; }

  //  public int? AnalyticsDataId { get; set; }
 //   public ICollection<AnalyticsData> AnalyticsDatas { get; set; }
}

  public class MedicalSpecialty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

  //  public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProgramDetailData> ProgramDetailDatas { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to get a User's associated MedicalSpecialty object it is NULL

```
 userSpecialtyName = currentUser.MedicalSpecialty.Description;
```

BUT when I run this code above it the currentUser.MedicalSpecialty is no longer NULL. What happened?? Somehow that LINQ query woke up the object and filled it with data

```
  var userSpecialtyId = currentUser.MedicalSpecialtyId;
            userSpecialtyName = _medicalSpecialtyRepository.Find
                                    (x => x.Id == userSpecialtyId).FirstOrDefault().Description;

            userSpecialtyName = currentUser.MedicalSpecialty.Description;
```

Comment: Is lazy loading and proxy creation enabled for the db context? Also this is EF6, not EF Core, right?

Comment: This is EF core.

Comment: Please update the tag then. And also except if you are using the 2.1 version preview, check out the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation (lazy loading is not supported yet).

Comment: so should I use .include in the repository pattern as a solution ?

Comment: Correct. That's the only option so far.